# How do I add multiple stylesheet selectors?

Tags: python, qtstylesheets, pyside2

I'm adding a button to the application 'Nuke'. I've added a QToolButton, and now I want to style it. I removed the border, and now I want to add a :hover.
I seem to be able to only set one stylesheet. How would I go about adding a second selector, given I can only use one stylesheet?

This will override the top one:

```py
snapshotToolButton.setStyleSheet("#SnapShotButton {border : none;}")
snapshotToolButton.setStyleSheet("#SnapShotButton:hover {background-color : yellow;}")
```

This is my code:

```
snapshotToolButton = QtWidgets.QToolButton()
snapshotToolButton.setObjectName("SnapShotButton")
snapshotToolButton.setStyleSheet("#SnapShotButton {border : none;}")

snapshotToolButton.setBaseSize(12,12)
snapshotToolButton.setIcon(QtWidgets.QIcon("C:/Users/nfran/.nuke/icons/cameraIcon.png"))
snapshotToolButton.setToolTip("Take Snapshot")
c.parentWidget().layout().insertWidget(0,snapshotToolButton)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method "setStyleSheet" is SETTING the Stylesheet, not adding a new one, so you keep overriding the one you already set.

To specify multiple styles, try the following:

```
snapshotToolButton.setStyleSheet("#SnapShotButton {border: none;} #SnapShotButton:hover { background-color: pink; }")
```

Comment: Ahh.. I was so close in my tests. I had that but put it on a different line. Thank you!

Comment: Hehe. No worries, glad I helped you solve your issue :)